# Global index of array in FindAndDelete method in diffrent class singenton instance of array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class with a singlton method , and contains the array of all DVDs.

```
public class DvdCon
{
    private static ArrayList<Dvd> dvds;
    private static DvdCon instance;
    private static int i = 0;

    public DvdCon()
    {
        dvds = new ArrayList<Dvd>();
    }

    public static DvdCon getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new DvdCon();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void addDvd(Dvd d)
    {
        dvds.add(d);
    }

    public void deleteDvd(Dvd d)
    {
        dvds.remove(d);
    }

    public Dvd findDvd(String title)
    {
        int i = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        while (!found && i<=dvds.size()){

            if (title.equals (dvds.get(i).getTitle())){
                found = true;
            }
            else {
                i++;
            }

            if (found){                
                return dvds.get(i);
            }

        }
        return null;
    }    
}
```

If we look at the `i` index variable that is a local variable in the method `findDvd`, I want to use that global in this class :

```
public class DvdCtr
{
    private DvdCon dCon;
    private Dvd dvd;

    public DvdCtr()
    {
        dCon = new DvdCon();
    }

    public void createDvd(String barcode, String title, String artist, String publicationDate)
    {
        Dvd d = new Dvd(barcode, title, artist, publicationDate);
        dCon.addDvd(dvd);
    }

    public Dvd findDvd(String title)
    {
        return dCon.findDvd(title);
    }

    public void updateDvd(Dvd d, String barcode, String title, String artist, String publicationDate)
    {
        dvd.setBarcode(barcode);
        dvd.setTitle(title);
        dvd.setArtist(artist);
        dvd.setPublicationDate(publicationDate);
    }

    public void deleteDvd(Dvd dvd)
    {
        dCon.deleteDvd(dvd);
    }

    public void findAndDeleteDvd()
    {
        dvd.getTitle();
        {               
            boolean found = false;
            while (!found && dvd.getTitle(i)){

                if (title.equals (dCon.getInstance().dvds.get(dCon.getInstance().i).getTitle())){
                    found = true;
                }
                else {
                    i++;
                }

                if (found){                
                    deleteDvd();
                }

            }
            return null;
        }
    }    
}
```

Now here in `findAndDeleteDVD` method I want to use the `i` index because its a singleton instance of the original array. So I don't want a new array list, I want it to look into the actual list.

But when I try to make a global field, the constructor from the original class stops to work because of the `int` ... How can I do this?

Again actual problem: Want to create one instance of the array so only one array exists and when I look in the index in the `findAndDeleteDvd` I find the actual global result of what is in the list and not a new array instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I get the exact way your program works, but here a suggestion:

FYI: in `DvdCon` the fields don't need to be `static`.

In your `findAndDeleteDvd()` you might need some changes. The code you posted above, does not make much sense :)

If you search by title, then you need to pass the title to the method

```
public void findAndDeleteDvd(String title) {   // pass the title to the method
    Dvd foundDvd = dCon.findDvd(title);        // findDvd by title and save a local reference (no need for it to be global
    deleteDvd(foundDvd);                       // delete the dvd (by its reference)
}
```

So far so good. Another suggestion to facilitate your search algorithm for finding a dvd by its title:

in `DvdCon`:

```
public Dvd findDvd(String title) {
    for (Dvd dvd : dvds) {          // loops through the whole list of dvds
        if (dvd.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title)) {   // compares the dvd's title with the parameter title
            return dvd;  // if equal, return dvd
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

That way you only need the `title` and no index. Handling indices is a direct approach but you might stumble over more problems. For example you cannot always be sure that the order of the elements in the list is always the same (e.g. what happens if you remove an element). What happens if one day you decide to use a HashMap instead of an ArrayList... etc.

So: pass the title to the search method and search for the title not by index. 
Well, I hope it helps in some way :)